# Using Elastic MapReduce on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

I plan to run mapreduce job on the data stored in S3. Data size is around 1PB. Will EMR copy entire 1TB data to spawned VMs with replication factor 3 (if my rf = 3)? If yes, does amazon charge for copying data from S3 to MapReduce cluster?

Also, is it possible to use EMR for the data not residing in s3?

Answer (score 1):

**Amazon Elastic Map Reduce** accesses data directly from Amazon S3. It does not copy the data to HDFS. (It might use some local temp storage, I'm not 100% sure.)

However, it certainly **won't trigger your HDFS replication factor**, since the data is not stored in HDFS. For example, Task Nodes that don't have HDFS can still access data in S3.

There is **no Data Transfer charge** for data movements between Amazon S3 and Amazon EMR within the same Region, but it will count towards the S3 Request count.

Amazon Elastic Map Reduce can certainly be used on data not residing in Amazon S3 -- it's just a matter of loading the data from your data source, such as using `scp` to copy the data into HDFS. Please note that the contents of HDFS will disappear when your cluster terminates. That's why S3 is a good place to store data for EMR -- it is persistent and there is no limit on the amount of data that is stored.

Comment: Thanks for replying John! Map step of mapreduce needs one block of data. How does it figure where block is starting and ending? Also, in this case, data is going to computation and not the other way - computation going to data, which is main principle of mapreduce.

Comment: @TarunKumar -- Not sure, that's deep Hadoop stuff, not necessarily EMR-specific.